# Python: Get substring of a string with a closest match to another string

Tags: python, string-comparison, levenshtein-distance

A nice algorithmic trivia for you today. :)

I have two strings – one is a longer sentence and the another one is shorter sentence that was discovered by LLM within the longer one. Let's see an example:

- **Long sentence:** "If you're a coder you should consider buying a MacBook Pro 15inch with an M2 from Apple that will provide you with a plenty of computing power for your AI use-cases."
- **Short sentence:** "Apple MacBook Pro 15" M2"

I need to mark the long sentence string with what is closest to the short string. The outcome would be the char `[start:end]` position indexes.

Acceptable outcomes could be like this (one of):

```
If you're a coder you should consider buying a MacBook Pro 15inch with an M2 from Apple that will provide you with a plenty of computing power for your AI use-cases.
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [47:65]
/or/
If you're a coder you should consider buying a MacBook Pro 15inch with an M2 from Apple that will provide you with a plenty of computing power for your AI use-cases.
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [47:76]
/or/
If you're a coder you should consider buying a MacBook Pro 15inch with an M2 from Apple that will provide you with a plenty of computing power for your AI use-cases.
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [47:87]
```

I considered:

- membership operator,
- `difflib` methods,
- regex,
- Levenshtein,

but nothing really suits the case.

The closes to what I can think of is this:

1. Get the `length = len(short_string)`.
2. Split `long_string` by whitespace into a set of substrings of `length` length.
3. Calculate Levenshtein difference between `short_string` and each substring.
4. The closest distance wins it.

```
short_string = "four five eight"
long_string = "one two three four five six seven eight nine"

length = 3

substrings = [
  "one two three",
  "two three four",
  "three four five",
  "four five six",
  "five six seven",
  "six seven eight",
  "seven eight nine"
]

for sentence in substrings:
  Levenshtein.distance(sentence, short_string)

winner = "four five six"
```

Any other ideas or open-source tools that you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should work reasonably well for your purpose:

1. Split the short sentence into words and join them into a regex of alternation pattern separated by `|`s.
2. Find all matches of the regex within the long sentence with `re.finditer`, which yields `re.Match` objects with the starting and ending indices of each match of a word in the short sentence.
3. Use `itertools.combinations` to generate all combinations of pairs of `Match` objects. Each pair of `Match` objects will be used to slice the long sentence with the starting index of the first `Match` object and the ending index of the second.
4. Use the `max` function to pick from the combinations of `Match` object pairs with the highest similarity ratio of the sliced long sentence and the short sentence, as calculated by [`difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio):

So with:

```
import re
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from itertools import combinations

def closest_substring(long, short):
    a, b = max(
        combinations(re.finditer('|'.join(short.split()), long), 2),
        key=lambda c: SequenceMatcher(None, long[c[0].start():c[1].end()], short).ratio()
    )
    return long[a.start():b.end()]
```

The following code:

```
long_string = "If you're a coder you should consider buying a MacBook Pro 15inch with an M2 from Apple that will provide you with a plenty of computing power for your AI use-cases."
short_string = 'Apple MacBook Pro 15" M2'
print(closest_substring(long_string, short_string))
```

will output:

```
MacBook Pro 15inch with an M2
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBatwwEIbvfophL5ZhY5KUQlnIIbnlsKXQ47IEWR6vlcgaZTRuaui7byXbSZsQHWxm9M83/4zCJD35L98Cn892CMQCjEXHNEBru87ZBtb0T3we0RvcazE98qKxgixELr6qDA2N9Vos@VgULXZgHEWM8hDHJgpbf1KO/GkLsU/6aldAOnoLDdzAoH@rOc7nf5JirDvr29xOlX/K@pGsVzOhjsFZUVW1hcxNv@tq@wZ5wunG6aFpNZjdxxHUd/K4lB3M4fJYR9GcUDtzuDrW6FtVHV991pydqGomL19GGdkv5fqttlkLiyJfPCwjp9k29x1MNJaMkLxQi5zDTB9dmxI@2pxrxinrNey1uSN6gh9McPXVetPDi5UetIf9NczLvw3BIUivJV05B4HpV4LM3EULSeBlAuryOsMomR3oJTXqaDbAcHsPY8QLo9Mr1ZtiHvef7XJp8t7NJlkoi5Akoj5/3hWwbm@Nqup8/gs)